# Static Final Ints in Switch: Why can't this be done?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

I had a Switch referencing Resource Ids from R.java in a Library Project:

```
switch (code) {

    case R.id.code_one:
        blah();
        break;
    case R.id.code_two:
        bleh();
        break;
}
```

From ADT 14, R fields are no longer final, so Google suggests to change the switch into nested if's. Fair enough.

However, I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
final int CODE_ONE=R.id.code_one, CODE_TWO=R.id.code_two;
switch (code) {

    case CODE_ONE:
        blah();
        break;
    case CODE_TWO:
        bleh();
        break;
}
```

or this:

```
class blih {
    private final static int CODE_ONE=R.id.code_one, CODE_TWO=R.id.code_two;
    void bluh(int code) {
        switch (code) {

            case CODE_ONE:
                blah();
                break;
            case CODE_TWO:
                bleh();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

All them complain with the error "Case statements must be constant expressions" ... aren't they, specially the first one? Whichever the value R.id.xxx might be, aren't I "finalizing" it into a snapshot constant?

Comment: Wrap them in class or use enum

Comment: Yes this can be done. If Tou will post more code i will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case statements must be constant expressions at compile time. If you initialize them at runtime, they are not constants.

`final` does not mean "compile-time constant". It only means "can be assigned only once". This does enable the compiler to inline values at compile-time if the final value is known, allowing initialized `final int`s to be used in case expressions.

Comment: hmmm i get it... it's all about inlining at compile time, then!

Comment: @rupps Yes and runtime-initialized values cannot be inlined.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because:

- The case label in the switch statement must be a **compile-time constant expression**.
- Your final variables `CODE_ONE` and `CODE_TWO` are not compile-time constant expressions because they are not initialized with compile-time constant expressions.

The requirement for case labels to be compile-time constant expressions:

- Is *necessary* so that the compiler can check that no two of the case labels have the same value.
- Allows the compiler to [compile all switch statements into table-driven byte code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10) at compile-time.

#### Details from the language specification

From the Java language specification, [section 14.11: The `switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> These labels are said to be associated with the switch statement, as are the values
>   of the constant expressions (§15.28) or enum constants (§8.9.1) in the case labels.

and:

> - No two of the case constant expressions associated with a switch statement may have the same value.

From the Java language specification, [section 15.28: **Constant Expressions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)*:

> 15.28. Constant Expressions
>   ...
>   A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - ... [other examples elided]
> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).
> - Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form TypeName . Identifier that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

The JLS on **constant variables**, in [section 4.12.4: `final` Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> 4.12.4 final Variables
>   ...
>   A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a
>   compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable.

Comment: +1 for the thorough explanation, however I like @laalto 's answer better because it's simpler and resumes all the docs. Thanks for linking all the official docs !

Comment: @rupps - Okay, I finished writing this more precise answer, for the benefit of those who come to your question in the future. Good point about simplicity; I separated the JLS extracts into a separate details section.